# HashiCorp Vault + Spring Boot. Client SSL configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to connect to Vault server from my Spring Boot application.
So, I walked trough this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vault
and getting the SSLHandshakeException:

```
WARN  o.s.v.a.LifecycleAwareSessionManager - Cannot enhance VaultToken to a LoginToken: Token self- 
lookup failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error 
on GET request for 

"https://*my vault server*/auth/token/lookup- 
self": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target
16:49:40.487 [http-nio-8084-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for 
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request 
for "https://*my vault server*/": 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target] with root cause
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path 
to requested target
```

So, I've put the keystore.jks in resources folder and pasted following configs to application.yml:

```
spring.cloud.vault:
ssl:
    trust-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    trust-store-password: changeit
```

And still getting an error. What am I doing wrong?
Is there any ways to set ssl verification to false, like I did in Postman?

Comment: You need to import keyvault server certificate in java `cacerts` use `keytool` command to imports.

Comment: @PandeyAmit Do you mean this one - import -trustcacerts -alias root -file my-root.cer -keystore keystore.jks ? Already did.

Comment: Better to import in `JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts` or you can use this way `java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password your-app.jar`

Comment: @PandeyAmit Yes! It did worked. Thank u very much!

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable the ssl on vault?